# Размер массива по кол-ву элементов

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Приветствую всех вошедших

```
// Собственно цикл, выводящий поочередно члены массива
int i[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
    cout<<i[j];
}
cin.get();
return 0;
```

Можно ли узнать/вывести размер массива по кол-ву его элементов? Казалось бы я это мог загуглить - и делов то.. но везде натыкаюсь на strlen, т.е. длинну переменной или на подсчет объема памяти, а самого счетчика элементов - нет/не_нашел.

Comment: В C/C++ есть оператор sizeof. Он даёт объём занимаемой памяти (и часто используется для определения количества элементов)

      sizeof arr/sizeor(type_of_arr)

А если Вы хотите узнать объём занимаемой памяти, то умножте количество элементов на длину этого элемента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с шаблонами функций:

```
template<int N>
void h(Sample (&arr)[N])
{
    int count = N; //N is 10, so would be count!
    //you can even do this now:
    //int count = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);  it'll return 10!
}
Sample arr[10];
h(arr); //pass : same as before!
```

По-моему, можно и тип данных как шаблон передать, чтобы избавиться от Sample в заголовке функции... но я не уверен, очень давно не писал на C++

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839626/element-count-of-an-array-in-c

Comment: Ох, за ответ спасибо, пойду разбирать. Только если честно я только начал изучать с++, и ожидал чего то по проще

Answer (score 1):

```
int i[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

#define _countof(i) (sizeof(i)/sizeof(i[0]));
cout<<_countof(i);    
cin.get();
return 0;
```

Простейший вариант